# How do I pass a filter value up as part of the state and return it down as props, thereby filtering out certain items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

As of right now I have a list of 40 or so Menu items that are grocery stores, and I only have the option to display all of the 40 stores at one time. I am trying to implement a filter by using a drop-down menu where you select the name of a store and only display stores with that name. Here is my code for the filter in a file called 'MenuComponent.js':

```
class FilterForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values.filter);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.handleSubmit(values)}>
        <Control.select model=".filter" id="filter" name="filter" className="form-control">
          <option value="Safeway">Safeway</option>
          <option value="Whole Foods">Whole Foods</option>
          <option value="Luckys">Luckys</option>
          <option value="Sprouts">Sprouts</option>
        </Control.select>
        <Row className="form-group">
            <Col md={{size: 10, offset: 2}}>
                <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                    Filter
                </Button>
            </Col>
        </Row>
      </LocalForm>
    );
  };
}
```

As part of this file I have the actual menu component as such, also located in 'MenuComponent.js':

```
const Menu = (props) => {
    const menu = props.dishes.dishes.map((dish) => {
      return (
        <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} comments={props.comments.comments.filter((comments) => comments.dishId === dish.id)} />
        </div>
      );
  });

  if (props.dishes.isLoading) {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <Loading />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  else if (props.dishes.errMess) {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <h4>{props.dishes.errMess}</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  else
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <h3>STORES</h3>
            <FilterForm />
            <hr />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {menu}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

export default Menu;
```

I am getting the correct value for values.filter. My question is how do I pass up this values.filter and re-render my Menu item so that I am only displaying the items where dish.name === values.filter.

The parent component is in a file called 'MainComponent.js' and looks like this:

```
return (
        <div id="MainDiv">
            <Header />
                <TransitionGroup>
                    <CSSTransition key={this.props.location.key} classNames="page" timeout={300}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
                            <Route exact path="/aboutus" component={AboutPage} />
                            <Route exact path="/menu" component={() => <Menu dishes={this.props.dishes} comments={this.props.comments} />} />
                            <Route path="/menu/:dishId" component={DishWithId} />
                            <Route exact path="/contactus" component={() => <Contact resetFeedbackForm={this.props.resetFeedbackForm}
                                    postFeedback={this.props.postFeedback} />} />
                            <Redirect to="/home" />
                        </Switch>
                    </CSSTransition>
                </TransitionGroup>
          <Footer />
        </div>
    );
```

This is where I am mapping the state and dispatch to props:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        dishes: state.dishes,
        comments: state.comments,
        promotions: state.promotions,
        leaders: state.leaders
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    postComment: (dishId, rating, author, comment, masks, carts, sanitizer, monitor, oneway, register, card, numcust, gloves, curb, delivery) => dispatch(postComment(dishId, rating, author, comment, masks, carts, sanitizer, monitor, oneway, register, card, numcust, gloves, curb, delivery)),
    fetchDishes: () => {dispatch(fetchDishes())},
    resetFeedbackForm: () => { dispatch(actions.reset('feedback'))},
    fetchComments: () => {dispatch(fetchComments())},
    fetchPromos: () => {dispatch(fetchPromos())},
    fetchLeaders: () => {dispatch(fetchLeaders())},
    postFeedback: (firstname, lastname, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message) => dispatch(postFeedback(firstname, lastname, telnum, email, agree, contactType, message))
});
```

Comment: Do I need to implement my FilterForm in MainComponent instead of MenuComponent and then pass down values.filter into the Menu component?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass down a function from Menu that will be used in FilterForm to set a state variable in Menu. When FilterForm updates the state variable in Menu, the Menu will re-render with the new filter.

Since Menu is a functional component you can use the useState hook.

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null);
  ...
  // then pass the function to FilterForm
  <h3>STORES</h3>
    <FilterForm setFilter={setFilter} />
  <hr />
```

Add the setFilter to FilterForm onSubmit

```
handleSubmit(values) {
  console.log(values.filter);
  this.props.setFilter(values.filter); // calls Menu's setFilter
}
```

Now we have that value back in Menu

```
const Menu = (props) => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null);

  let dishes = props.dishes.dishes;
  if(filter !== null){
    // not sure if you call it storeName or something else, but filter the list
    dishes = dishes.filter((dish) => dish.storeName === filter);
  }

  // and then do map with the filtered list
  const menu = dishes.map((dish) => {
    return (
      <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
          <RenderMenuItem dish={dish} comments={props.comments.comments.filter((comments) => comments.dishId === dish.id)} />
      </div>
    );
  });
  ...
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! Works like a charm! Had to use React.useState(null) but everything else is exactly like you said.